# How to replace .drl file dynamically while using drools in mule esb?

Tags: mule, drools, esb

what i need is to replace the .drl file dynamically. through some nasty code i am able to load the .drl file and change the content but it seems that drools holds on to its initial file.

these are my config files (just in case):

**mule-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:quartz="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz"
      xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
      xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms"
      xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
      xmlns:bpm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/bpm"
      xmlns:client="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/client"

        xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" 
        xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"   
        xmlns:management="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/management"


    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.2/mule.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz/3.2/mule-quartz.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/3.2/mule-vm.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/3.2/mule-jms.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/3.2/mule-scripting.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/bpm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/bpm/3.2/mule-bpm.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/client http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/client/3.2/mule-client.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd

    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/management http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/management/current/mule-management.xsd

        ">

    <bpm:jbpm /> 
    <bpm:drools />    

    <!-- Define EMC Routing facts bean -->
    <spring:bean name="NoFactsBean" class="java.util.ArrayList"/>

    <jms:activemq-connector 
                    name="jms-connector"                     
                    brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" 
                    disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true"
                    specification="1.1"/>

    <jms:endpoint name="UnsortedOrders" queue="UnsortedOrders"/>                
    <jms:endpoint name="DestinationEMC" queue="DestinationEMC"/>                
    <jms:endpoint name="DestinationOriginal" queue="DestinationOriginal"/>                

    <vm:endpoint name="DroolsEndpoint" path="drools"/>

   <!-- GOLI --> 
   <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="dto-convertor" class="com.hamgam.hit.esb.XMLToDTO" scope="singleton" />
        <spring:bean id="rule-convertor" class="com.hamgam.hit.esb.RuleXMLToDRL" scope="singleton" />           
    </spring:beans>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener" host="localhost" port="8084" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />
    <!-- /GOLI --> 

    <flow name="RestEtryPoint">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener" path="/{name}" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <set-variable variableName="name" value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.uri.params']['name']]" />        
        <set-variable variableName="msg" value="#[payload]"/>
        <expression-component>
            app.registry['dto'] = app.registry['dto-convertor'].convert(flowVars['name']);
        </expression-component>
        <set-payload value="#[app.registry['dto']]"/>                    
        <jms:outbound-endpoint ref="UnsortedOrders"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="***************Entry***************" />         

    </flow>                    

    <flow name="jBPMProcess">
        <composite-source>
            <vm:inbound-endpoint path="in" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
            <jms:inbound-endpoint ref="UnsortedOrders"/>
        </composite-source>  
        <!-- TODO streaming="false"Transform XML to object -->
        <bpm:process processName="DecisionRouting" processDefinition="routing-process.jpdl.xml"/>    
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="***************JBPM Process***************" />                                                                       
    </flow>

    <flow name="DroolsFlow">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint ref="DroolsEndpoint" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
        <bpm:rules rulesDefinition="emcRoutingRules.drl" initialFacts-ref="NoFactsBean" />
        <expression-transformer evaluator="groovy" expression="message.getPayload().getObject()"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="***************Drools Flow***************" />

    </flow> 


     <flow name="ConsumeEmcQ">
        <jms:inbound-endpoint ref="DestinationEMC"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="*************Consume Q4 DestinationEMC*****************" />

        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[payload]" />              
    </flow>
    <flow name="ConsumeOrigQ">
        <jms:inbound-endpoint ref="DestinationOriginal"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="*************Consume Q4 DestinationOriginal*****************" />                   
    </flow>


</mule>
```

this is **routing-process.jpdl.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<process description="routing example" name="DecisionRouting" xmlns="http://jbpm.org/4.3/jpdl">

    <mule-receive name="unsortedOrder" endpoint="UnsortedOrders" type="com.hamgam.hit.esb.XMLDTO" var="order">
        <transition to="sendToDrools" />
    </mule-receive>

    <mule-send name="sendToDrools" expr="#{order}" endpoint="DroolsEndpoint" exchange-pattern="request-response" var="order">
        <transition to="defineDestination" />
    </mule-send>

    <decision name="defineDestination">
        <transition to="sendToEMC">
            <condition expr="#{order.destination == 'EMC'}" />
        </transition>
        <transition to="sendToOriginalDest">
            <condition expr="#{order.destination == 'ORIG'}" />
        </transition>

        <transition to="routingFailed" />
    </decision>

    <mule-send name="sendToEMC"
          expr="#{order}" endpoint="DestinationEMC" exchange-pattern="one-way">
        <transition to="routingSuccessful" />
    </mule-send>

    <mule-send name="sendToOriginalDest"
          expr="#{order}" endpoint="DestinationOriginal" exchange-pattern="one-way">
        <transition to="routingSuccessful" />
    </mule-send>

    <end name="routingSuccessful" />

    <end name="routingFailed" />

</process>
```

and this is **emcRoutingRules.drl** that originally placed in resource folder :

```
package com.hamgam.hit.esb

import com.hamgam.hit.esb.*; 
import org.mule.MessageExchangePattern

global org.mule.module.bpm.MessageService mule;

# default dialect for the semantic code will be MVEL
dialect "mvel"

declare XMLDTO
    @role( event )
end 

rule "Select Emc"
    lock-on-active

when
     $x:XMLDTO(inputXML == "moien")    
then
   modify( $x ) { setDestination("EMC") }
end

rule "Select Original Destination"
    lock-on-active

when
    $x:XMLDTO( inputXML == "goli" )
then
   modify( $x ) { setDestination("ORIG") }
end
```

and this is how i am replacing the .drl file :

```
private void generateFile(String rule) throws IOException{
PrintWriter writer;
try {
    ClassLoader classLoader = RuleXMLToDRL.class.getClassLoader();
    File file =
      new File(classLoader.getResource("emcRoutingRules.drl").getFile());
    writer = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8");
    writer.println(""
            + "package com.hamgam.hit.esb "
            + "import com.hamgam.hit.esb.*; "
            + "import org.mule.MessageExchangePattern "
            + "global org.mule.module.bpm.MessageService mule; "
            + "dialect \"mvel\" declare XMLDTO @role( event ) end");
    writer.println(rule);
    writer.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Just replacing a .drl file while a Drools session is ongoing isn't enough - you may have to recompile and restart.

Comment: i need to avoid restarting. is there a way to tell mule to rebuild it self?

Comment: i have noticed that change in mule-config file leads to rebuild. is there a way to use that in my favor?

Comment: I know something about Drools but nothing about mule. The configuration XML Schema http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/bpm/3.6/mule-bpm.xsd doesn't contain anything that would indicate such a feature.

Comment: Within limits, it might be possible to modify the way rules work by means of additional facts, i.e., not just XMLDTO objects. But you'll need access to the Drools session object.

Comment: "...change...rebuild" This sounds reasonable, but a rebuild isn't the same as using the result of a rebuild.

Comment: i am googling about rebuild via maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not proud, but i came up with a hacker solution:

as i mentioned before any change on mule-config.xml file will lead to mules rebuild, so after changing .drl file i am making a dummy change to mule-config.xml file too.

```
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("mule-config.xml", true)));
        out.println("<!-- -->");
        out.flush();
```

note that the solution wont work if you lunch from Anypoint studio. but deploy it in mule standalone and it will work.

Till i find a better solution, this works just fine ;)